# My function to copy the content of a file to an array doesn't work out properly

Tags: arrays, c, memory

I'd like to read the content of a file and copy it to an array and return this array, the fonction work but it is kind of hectic it have memory issues and i have to set End Of File caracter 17 character before the end of the file data in order not to read memory which i shouldn't be reading because otherwise im getting weird character like " ═════════════════²²²²".

Here is my code :

```
static char* readShader(const char* filepath)
{
    FILE* file;

    fopen_s(&file, filepath, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open shader file");
        return NULL;
    }
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    const int size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(size + 1); 
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory");
        return NULL;
    }
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), size, file);
    buffer[size-17] = '\0';
    fclose(file);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre] as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result. As a new user please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `fopen_s(&file, filepath, "rb");` (*if it works the same as `fopen()`; I haven't read about `fopen_s()`*) to avoid translation of `"\r\n"` in file to `"\n"` in memory. *I guess your file has 17 lines (give or take)*

Comment: "the function work" everything in your question tells the opposite.

Comment: `fread` returns a number of read elements. You should use it.

Comment: My file has 18 lines i guess the EOF character has something to do with it

Comment: `EOF` is not a character, it's a signal. Somewhat like if you ask a girl her age and she says `"GO AWAY"` ... `"GO AWAY"` is a signal, not an age

Comment: @G4143 laughing at newbies it not very helpful or welcoming.

Comment: like @Gerhardh said im quite newbie to programming and i often commit mistakes

Comment: Simplify the file to read (few characters, less lines) and use the debugger to see what you have read in contrast to your expectations. If you are on Windows, learn about the different end-of-line markers.

Comment: my file is code written in GLSL and i'll have to modifiy it so i can't simplify it

Comment: Well, right away you should be storing the number of bytes read from the file so you where to end your c-string with '\0'.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it copied the data 'hopefully' correctly into the buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char* readShader(const char* filepath)
{
    FILE* file;
    size_t read_bytes = 0;
    
    file = fopen(filepath, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
      printf("Could not open shader file");
      return NULL;
    }
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    const int size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(size + 1); 
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
      printf("Could not allocate memory");
      return NULL;
    }
    read_bytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), size, file);
    buffer[read_bytes] = '\0';
    fclose(file);
    return buffer;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    char *data = readShader("datafile");//I just hardcoded it for "datafile"
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", data);
    return 0;
}
```

You'll have to check for one-off errors in the buffer.

Comment: You [can not use `ftell()` to get the size of a file in text mode](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2): "The `ftell` function obtains the current value of the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream. ... For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the `fseek` function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the `ftell` call; **the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read**."

Comment: And code that uses [`fseek()` to get to the end of a binary stream isn't portable](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268):  "Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, **has undefined behavior for a binary stream** ..."  `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file is fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 0):

Thank, this work fine i've also found out that using calloc set to zero the memory allocated and thus this code work too because of the garbage value being set to zero.

```
static char* readShader(const char* filepath)
{
    FILE* file;

    fopen_s(&file, filepath, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open shader file\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    const int size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    char* buffer = (char*)calloc(size + 1, sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), size, file));
    fclose(file);
    return buffer;
}
```